# Indirectly expand variables in shell

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, variable, arguments

I need to indirectly reference a variable in the `bash` shell.

I basically want to what you can do in `make` by writing `$($(var))`.

I have tried using `${$var}` which would be the most straight forward solution in `bash` but then I get this error:

```
bash: ${$var}: bad substitution
```

Is there a way to do this?

What I am trying to do is to iterate over all the arguments (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ...) to a program using an iteration variable and I cannot do this without indirection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have `var1=foo` and `foo=bar`, you can get `bar` by saying `${!var1}`. However, if you want to iterate over the positional parameters, it's almost certainly better to do

```
for i in "$@"; do
    # something
done
```

Comment: Is there a way to add multiple levels of indirection?

Comment: Not that I can quickly find. The obvious guess of `${!!var1}` doesn't work. However, you can always do it manually, e.g. `tmp=${!var1}; echo ${!tmp}`.

Comment: You don't even need to write `in "$@"`. Just `for i; do #something; done` is enough.

Answer (score 7):

Using `/bin/bash`:

```
foo=bar
test=foo
echo ${!test}

# prints -> bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Using grep + awk

```bsh
foo=bar
var_name=foo
set | grep -v var_name | grep ^"${var_name}=" | awk -F= '{ print $2 }'
```

the output will be

```
bar
```

To prove that this approach works, check the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function show_variable_value() {
  name=$1
  value=$(set | grep -v name | grep ^"${name}="  | awk -F= '{ print $2 }' )
  echo "${value}"
}


foo='bar'

# getting the variable value indirectly from the variable name
value=$(show_variable_value foo)
if [ "${value}" == "${foo}" ]; then
  echo "The function returned indirectly the variable value from the variable name >>> '${value}' == '${foo}'"
else
  echo "This approach does not work"
fi
```

Comment: Doesn't that still expand the variable directly in the second grep?

Comment: It was a typo on the second `grep`, it was missing a $ character => `grep $test`. Please, upvote instead because it's working as you can see in the bash script above.

Comment: Can you perhaps add more explanation to this answer? I think you are dumping environment with set, grepping away the line starting with the outer variable name, then grepping for the content of that variable, presumably to pull out the name it references and outputting it. However, wouldn't the value of `test` be `bar` since you set it to `$foo`?

Comment: The function `show_variable_value()` is getting the first argument as the variable name and as you explained, it's not presumably, it really gets the value of the variable indirectly (using the variable name), the value of the `test` variable will be => `"bar"`. Please, try to execute the script, play a bit with the script setting different values to the variable foo and you will see it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I made an adjustment in the first section, it had one extra `$` and instead of getting the variable name was getting the variable value. Instead of `test`, to be more cohesive I am using `var_name`.

Comment: Adding that exlpanation into the answer will improve its quality.