# get environment variable by variable name?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

For example, I have a variable:

```
env_name="GOPATH"
```

Now I want to get the environment variable `GOPATH` as if like this:

```
echo $GOPATH
```

How can I get `$GOPATH` by `$env_name`?

Comment: `printenv $env_name`

Comment: Or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222487/bash-dynamic-variable-variable-names?lq=1

Comment: See here for most awesome answer by awesome dude -> http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229849/indirectly-expand-variables-in-shell

Comment: in this case, `printenv GOPATH` meaning you can alias such as `alias p='printenv'` and then it's just `p GOPATH`. Get any environment variable by just typing `p` instead of the more clumsy `echo $...`

Answer (score 70):

Different shells have different syntax for achieving this.

In `bash`, you use [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-expansion_002c-parameter):

```
printf '%s\n' "${!env_name}"
```

In `ksh`, you use `nameref` aka `typeset -n`:

```
nameref env_name=GOPATH
printf '%s\n' "$env_name"
```

In `zsh`, you use `P` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-flags_002c-parameter-expansion):

```
print -rl -- ${(P)env_name}
```

In other shell, you must use [eval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23111/38906), which put you under many security implications if you're not sure the variable content is safe:

```
eval "echo \"\$$name_ref\""
```

Comment: in `bash` I used `printf '%s\n' "${env_name}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `eval` if you let a shell's prompt expansion handle the indirection:

```
PS1=\$$env_name sh -si </dev/null 2>&1
```

This has some advantages - particularly in that the expansion is not followed by command execution. And so the only hazard here is if `$env_name` contains a command substitution. The variable which it expands to can contain anything which might look like a command substitution without danger because the expansion isn't attempted three times - only twice. In this way validation is fairly easy:

```
PS1=$"${env_name##*[\'\(]*}" sh -si </dev/null 2>&1
```

Given a POSIX `sh`, that should be plenty safe without any risk of arbitrary code execution, while still printing any exported environment variables *(of the kind a shell can understand)* to standard-out.

Comment: hmm I can't seem to get this to work, just outputs a blank string ?