# pass function parameter as name instead of as a string

Tags: bash, shell-script

With this function:

```
repr() {
    declare -p $1 | cut -d '=' -f 2- > /tmp/.repr
    $1=$(</tmp/.repr)
    rm /tmp/.repr
}
```

It gives an error message, when I write:

```
repr test
```

This see the argument as string:

```
repr() {
    declare -p 'test' | cut -d '=' -f 2- > /tmp/.repr
    'test'=$(</tmp/.repr)
    rm /tmp/.repr
}
```

And not as name:

```
repr() {
    declare -p test | cut -d '=' -f 2- > /tmp/.repr
    test=$(</tmp/.repr)
    rm /tmp/.repr
}
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Instead of `typeset -p | cut` use `printf %q` (see the update to my A to your previous Q. Eg. `repr() { repr() { printf -v "$1" %q "$2"; }` to use as `repr varname string`: `repr q "e's f"; echo "$q"` => `e\'s\ f`.

Comment: In general, you can pass variable by names via references (`declare -n`): `set_to_13(){ declare -n v=$1; v=13; }; set_to_13 var; echo "$var"` => `13`.

Comment: Be aware that the nameref persists: if you `unset v` it will unset var and leave v defined. You erase the nameref with `unset -n v`.

Comment: printf -v bar %q "$foo" in the function is read like: printf -v 'bar' %q "$foo", but despite this, it continues to work. Thank you very much

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, no need to explicitly unset the nameref if it's just used inside that function (`declare` inside a function makes it local).

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to print the content of the content of a variable with shell script? (indirect referencing)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/452723/170373), [get environment variable by variable name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251893/170373), [Use a variable reference “inside” another variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41406/170373)

Comment: @ilkkachu Didn't know that, but it is pretty mucky. `local -n` also declares a nameref. `declare -g -n` makes the reference global. `local - ` gives a function a local copy of the shell args that it can modify. Too many special rules around!

Comment: I am confused. What are you trying to do? Edit the question to give a simple minimal **But less abstract** example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716607/creating-a-string-variable-name-from-the-value-of-another-string